# Índice dinámico para regla en base de datos usando Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, indices

Quisiera saber si existe alguna manera de crear un índice o alguna función en oracle pero que solo aplique bajo ciertas condiciones, por ejemplo mi sistema por medio de su email, un usuario puede tener varios perfiles asignados a ese mismo mail.

Primero comparto mis tablas usuarios y perfil sin índices

```
CREATE TABLE "USUARIOS"
  (
    "ID_USUARIO"              NUMBER,
    "NOMBRE"                  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    "PATERNO"                 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    "MATERNO"                 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    "EMAIL"                   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    "NUMERO_SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
    CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY ("ID_USUARIO")
  );

CREATE TABLE "PERFILES"
  (
    "ID_PERFIL" NUMBER,
    "ID_USUARIO",
    CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY ("ID_USUARIO") REFERENCES "USUARIOS"("ID_USUARIO")
  );
```

Al hacer esto puedo insertar dos registros con información duplicada en la tabla Usuarios solo con diferente id que es su primary key

```
insert into usuarios values(1,'j', 'a', 'm','jjam@mail.com',123456);
insert into usuarios values(2,'j', 'a', 'm','jjam@mail.com',123456);
```

Lo siguiente seria borrar estos dos registros para poder crear el ÍNDICE

```
delete from usuarios where id_usuario in(1,2);
```

Creamos el índice único para poder evitar la situación anterior

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "USUARIOS_EMAIL_NSS_UNICO" ON "USUARIOS" ("EMAIL","NUMERO_SEGURIDAD_SOCIAL") ;
```

Ahora intento insertar los mismos registros de antes

```
insert into usuarios values(1,'j', 'a', 'm','jjam@mail.com',123456);
insert into usuarios values(2,'j', 'a', 'm','jjam@mail.com',123456);
```

Pero cuando intento ingresar el segundo registro me arrojará:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint (**USUARIOS_EMAIL_NSS_UNICO**) violated
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
```

Como ven un indice tambien sirve para poder restringir los datos que ingresamos y también me da las capacidades de búsqueda, ya que ahora al querer buscar por medio del email o del nss se hara la busqueda mejorada por índices.

Por otro lado y habiendo explicado el por que dije "crear un índice o alguna cosa en particular", el resultado que quisiera saber es lo siguiente

Teniendo en la tabla Usuario la información como sigue

```
id | nombre | paterno | materno | email      | nss
 1 |    j   |    a    |    m    | j@mail.com | 123456
```

Me gustaria saber si en la tabla perfiles existe alguna forma de crear la siguiente lógica por medio de oracle

```
  idPerfil | idUsuario  | Año Fiscal |            | 
  -------------------------------------------------
   1       | 1          |  2014                   | 
   1       | 1          |  2015                   | 
   1       | 1          |  2016                   | 
   2       | 1          |  2016                   |
```

En donde:

- idPerfil 1 es un perfil Organizacion
- idPerfil 2 es un perfil Administrador

Y donde solo quiero tener

1. Varios usuarios organizacion asignados al mismo mail pero en diferente año
   (Como dije antes puedo hacer esto creando un índice único donde diga que el idPerfil, idUsuario  y año fiscal son únicos)
2. Solo un perfil Administrador por email
   (El índice del punto uno choca con esta condición, por lo cual quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de realizar el índice de manera dinámica en donde si es perfil 1 permite muchos registros solo que el año no se repita pero si es administrador solo permite un solo registro ya que si lo dejo asi nada me impide agregar otro perfil administrador en un año diferente)

Comment: Si compartes detalles más concretos sobre las tablas/columnas implicados, probablemente puedo proponerte una solución.

Comment: Estas seguro que hablas de "indices"? Me parece que estas confundiendo conceptos. Un indice es el campo por el cual buscar. Se crea para el campo y listo. Si tiene o no datos, no importa. El DBMS se encarga de mantenerlo.

Comment: Esto es conocido como el "problema X Y". Tienes X problema y crees que la solución es Y. En lugar de preguntar cómo resolver X,  preguntas cómo hacer Y, pero Y no es la solución. Te sugiero que te concentres en explicar tu problema y con seguridad alguien te ayudará a encontrar la solución, pero no preguntes sobre índices, porque, hasta donde puedo ver, los índices no tienen nada que ver con solucionar tu problema (que no me queda del todo claro cual es).

Comment: @sstan edite mi pregunta para ver si es mas clara

Comment: Sí. Ayudaron mucho tus aclaraciones. Te dejé una respuesta al respecto. Comentario aparte, creo que sería más preciso que definieras 2 índices únicos separados en tu tabla `usuarios` para los campos `email` y `numero_seguridad_social` en vez de combinarlos en un solo como lo tienes ahora. De lo contrario, es posible repetir el mismo email varias veces con tal que el número de seguro social sea diferente. Allí tu sabrás qué hacer...

Comment: @sstan no sabía esa parte y gracias por aclararlo voy a usarlo como mencionas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que mencionas del *mail*, no lo entiendo completamente. Pero por tus ejemplos, esto es lo que comprendo:

En la tabla `perfiles`

- Si `id_perfil` es `1`, entonces la combinación `id_perfil, id_usuario, ano_fiscal` debe ser única.
- Pero si `id_perfil` es `2`, entonces solo la combinación `id_perfil, id_usuario` debe considerarse única.

Si lo anterior es correcto, es posible definir un índice único *function-based* que incluye una expresión `CASE` que solo toma en cuenta el año fiscal cuando el `id_perfil` es `1`:

```
create unique index perfiles_idx on perfiles (
  id_perfil,
  id_usuario,
  case when id_perfil = 1 then ano_fiscal end);
```

Comment: Si de hecho era exactamente lo que quería hacer, lo del mail primeramente para explicar mi punto y también por que para mi es mi username junto con un password con los que me logueo al sistema y tengo q tener esa lógica que te comenté pero tal vez está un poco fuera de contexto para el problema que te presente, de cualquier manera muchas gracias